# Object doesn't support this property or method: 'document'

Tags: vbscript

When I was trying simple vb script to login gmail which inputs username and password automatically, got an error message "Object doesn't support this property or method: 'document'"

```
dim url
dim browser

url = "https://gmail.com"

set browser = createobject("wscript.shell")

browser.run(url)

wscript.sleep 100

set login = browser.document.getelementbyid("formUsername")

login.value = "sample@gmail.com"

set login = browser.document.getelementbyid("formpassword")

login.value = "password"

set login = browser.document.Forms(0)

login.submit

do while (browser.busy)

wscript.sleep 10

loop

msgbox "You've successfully logged"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.run(url)
```

browser is a shell object. It knows that running a URL will open whatever your default web browser is, and go to that URL. That's it. It won't expose the DOM elements to your script.

Comment: To expose DOM elements, what needs to be corrected in the script ??

Comment: @SatheeshKumar There are many questions on SO that will point you in the right direction eg https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: To get to the DOM you need a different object, look up: CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")